# Automatically move files to folders that corresponds with their respective number

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, file-move

I have a script that takes the a number as command-line argument and moves files with this number into the folder with the respective number.

#### Example

For example, I have 20 folders named `Episode 1` through `Episode 20`.
I also have a total of 120 files, 5 files per folder `file1-ep 1`, `file2-ep1` would move into folder `Episode 1`, and so on, all the way to `file1-ep20`, `file2-ep20` which would move into folder `episode 20`, etc.

#### Code

I already have the script to move the files.
It just requires me following on command line: `move.py 1` or `move.py 2`, etc.

My current script:

```py
import os
import sys
import shutil

path = "/Users/Macbook/Final Cut Pro/"

destination_path = f"/Users/Macbook/Final Cut Pro/episode {sys.argv[1]}/"

for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk(path):
    for f in file:
        f = f.lower()
        if check_file(sys.argv[1])in f:
            source = path + f
            destination = destination_path + f
            print(f)
            # shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Basically, I want the program to loop automatically instead of asking for user input. So that I would just need to supply the start and stop numbers.

#### What I tried

I've tried putting the nested `for` loops into another `for` loop.

```py
for i in range (1,21)

    for loop
    for loop
```

How can I make a loop so that it moves all the respective files into the folders without any user input?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your file is in the following format `file1-ep 1`. they you try this

```
start_number = 1
end_number = 20
for i in range(start_number, end_number+1):
    for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk(path):
        for f in file:
            f = f.lower()
            if i == int(re.findall(r'\d+', f)[0]):
                source = path + f
                destination = destination_path + f
                print(f)
                shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Comment: I already tried it, but it wouldn't work because when `i`  is 1 it would catch `1` `11` `21`, etc, and when `i` is `2` it would catch `22`, `12`, etc. Basically any file that contains `1` would get moved, which isn't what I want. thats why I called the function `checked_files` which would check for me..

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you check if it works?

Comment: Like I said, I already tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try the updated answer? And can you state the reason why the updated code doesn't work? Do you get any error?

Comment: you're "hard coding" the file name, the filename will not be in the format `file1-ep 1`, the filename could be anything (file1, file 1, ep1, ep.1. file.1. file. 1.), as long as it contains the corresponding folder number.

Comment: Okay, you can use regex to extract number from the file name, I have updated my answer, try it out.

Comment: I can tell it won't work without even testing it. First, your destination path is isn't in the loop, second you don't account for duplicate numbers. For example, when `i = 5` it will proceed to match all files with `5` in it. Including, `55` `15`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my idea of an outer loop was correct, only I was using `sys.argv[i]` instead of `i`. I also have to move the destination path inside the loop.

```
for i in range(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]) + 1):
    destination_path = f"/Users/Macbook/Final Cut Pro/episode {i}/"
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
            f = f.lower()
            if checked_files(i):
               #move files
```

Comment: Please explain (for others having the same issue) how this code uses the range from command line arguments. Also provide code for function `checked_files(i)` to have a [example].

Comment: How does the loop differ from [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74767066/5730279)? It is more complete, having the file-name matching and move-statement.

Comment: did you look at my answer? my answers uses cmd line arguments for the start and stop in the loop. dev740 loop is hardcoded, he assigns a start and stop of 1 and 20.

Comment: @dev740 edited his answer already, before it was not complete. I already posted my answer before he edited the current version.  "explain how this code uses the range from command line arguments"  Are you seriously asking how a basic `for loop` works? I take the arguments from cmd line, convert it to an `int` to tell the loop how many times to loop and when to stop .